# MySQL - GROUP_CONCAT with joins, produces 1054 error

Tags: mysql, sql

I tried to work off of the results of [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11920102/mysql-group-concat-with-joins), but nothing seems to work. I have a virtually identical setup, just with a different type of file.

**Files Table `files`**

```
id    file_name
 1    1e462cef-1c2c-4ddf-8b48-0b3002e2101d.nzb
 2    303dc268-bf55-49e5-9901-cfbb99b09a69.nzb
 3    1297993d-784b-4996-b3b9-9048b068652b.nzb
 4    a2cebf3a-b3b1-498e-ad4c-100774ff4b9d.nzb
```

**Tags Table `tags`**

```
id    tag_name
 1    no.mirrors
 2    at.least.one.mirror
 3    multiple.mirrors
 4    no.mirrors
 5    original.deleted
```

**Files-Tags Relationship Table `files__tags`**

```
file_id (FK to files.id)   tag_id (FK to tags.id)
      1                    1
      1                    5
      2                    1
      3                    3
      3                    5
      4                    4
```

So I was hoping to get some output like:

```
file_id   file_name                                   tags
      1   1e462cef-1c2c-4ddf-8b48-0b3002e2101d.nzb    1,5
      2   303dc268-bf55-49e5-9901-cfbb99b09a69.nzb    1
      3   1297993d-784b-4996-b3b9-9048b068652b.nzb    3,5
      4   a2cebf3a-b3b1-498e-ad4c-100774ff4b9d.nzb    4
```

I tried to recreate my query from the answer on that previous question as such:

```
SELECT files.file_name, GROUP_CONCAT(files__tags.tag_id) AS associated_tags
FROM files
LEFT OUTER JOIN tags ON files__tags.file_id = files.id
GROUP BY files.file_name;
```

I tried some other things, the answer on that question references a `tag.photo` which does not exist in the simplified table structure supplied by the person who asked the question, I assumed it was a typo for the table relating photos and tags.

Anyway the error I am getting is:

```
SQL query:

SELECT files.file_name, GROUP_CONCAT(files__tags.tag_id) AS associated_tags
FROM files
LEFT OUTER JOIN tags ON files__tags.file_id = files.id
GROUP BY files.file_name LIMIT 0, 25

MySQL said:
#1054 - Unknown column 'files__tags.tag_id' in 'field list'
```

All of the above columns exist.

Thanks much for any ideas!

**EDIT**: I have tried the two suggestions (adding the relational database to the `FROM` and escaping the table/column names)

```
SELECT files.file_name, GROUP_CONCAT(files__tags.tag_id) AS associated_tags
FROM files,files__tags
LEFT OUTER JOIN tags ON `files__tags`.`file_id` = `files`.`id`
GROUP BY files.file_name;
```

I also tried each of these things on their own, and escape all table/column names in the entire statement.

With escaping I get:

```
 #1054 - Unknown column 'files__tags.tag_id' in 'field list'
```

With the `files__tags` table named in `FROM` I get:

```
 #1054 - Unknown column 'files.id' in 'on clause'
```

**EDIT2**: OK, thanks much for the solution

```
SELECT files.file_name, GROUP_CONCAT(files__tags.tag_id) AS associated_tags
FROM files
LEFT JOIN files__tags ON files__tags.file_id =files.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN tags ON tags.id=files__tags.tag_id 
GROUP BY files.file_name LIMIT 0, 25
```

Comment: May i know what is this `files__tags`?

Comment: This is the table which relates files and tags (labeled them above)

Comment: So you have to mention that table in `JOIN` or `FROM` clause.

Comment: There is no table assigned to the alias files__tags that's why it is causing error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT files.file_name, GROUP_CONCAT(files__tags.tag_id) AS associated_tags
FROM files
LEFT JOIN files__tags ON files__tags.file_id =files.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN tags ON tags.id=files__tags.tag_id 
GROUP BY files.file_name LIMIT 0, 25
```

Try above code,hope this will helps

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why use `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. Try this

```
     SELECT files.file_name, GROUP_CONCAT(files__tags.tag_id) AS associated_tags
FROM files
LEFT JOIN files__tags ON files__tags.file_id =files.id
LEFT JOIN tags ON tags.id=files__tags.tag_id 
GROUP BY files__tags.file_id LIMIT 0, 25
```