# MySql: unknown column id in 'field list'

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am following the answer of this question:
[MySQL: is it possible to group_concat multiple rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11237428/mysql-is-it-possible-to-group-concat-multiple-rows)

But I struggle with the MySql error:

> `#1054 - Unknown column 'CM_Cocktail.id' in 'field list'`.

When I delete this CM_Cocktail.id stuff the next error apperars: `#1054 - Unknown column 'CM_Zutat.name' in 'field list'`. I tried to use aliases but it gone worse... Maybe I am blind.

```html
SELECT 
  CM_Cocktail.id, CM_Cocktail.name,
  GROUP_CONCAT(CM_Zutat.name SEPARATOR ', ')
FROM (
  SELECT CM_Cocktail.id, CM_Cocktail.name AS cname, CM_Zutat.name
              FROM CM_Cocktail, CM_CocktailHatZutat, CM_Zutat
              WHERE CM_Cocktail.id=CM_CocktailHatZutat.cocktail_id
              AND CM_CocktailHatZutat.zutat_id=CM_Zutat.id
) group_attr
GROUP BY CM_Cocktail.id;
```

```html
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `CM_Cocktail` (
  `id` int(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;
```

```html
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `CM_CocktailHatZutat` (
  `cocktail_id` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `zutat_id` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `zutat_menge` int(4) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

```html
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `CM_Zutat` (
  `id` int(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;
```

Comment: show your table schema.

Comment: Have look into table structure of CM_Cocktail, CM_CocktailHatZutat, CM_Zutat? Maybe provide it here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to define column alias in your sub query and than use alias as parent fields as this example:

```
SELECT 
CocktailID, cname,
GROUP_CONCAT(ZName SEPARATOR ', ')
FROM (
SELECT CM_Cocktail.id as CocktailID, CM_Cocktail.name AS cname, CM_Zutat.name as ZName
     FROM CM_Cocktail, CM_CocktailHatZutat, CM_Zutat
     WHERE CM_Cocktail.id=CM_CocktailHatZutat.cocktail_id
     AND CM_CocktailHatZutat.zutat_id=CM_Zutat.id
) group_attr
GROUP BY CocktailID;
```

Comment: @Sylverblade: glad to help u bro, everything is the part of learning my friend. :)

Comment: @devpro am Angel.can you help me??? am stucked in one query   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35646188/i-want-to-convert-this-query-in-codeigniter-to-ignited-datatable-query. please help

Answer (score 1):

plz try this

```
SELECT 
id, name,
GROUP_CONCAT(CM_Zutat.name SEPARATOR ', ')
FROM (
SELECT CM_Cocktail.id, CM_Cocktail.name AS cname, CM_Zutat.name
          FROM CM_Cocktail, CM_CocktailHatZutat, CM_Zutat
          WHERE CM_Cocktail.id=CM_CocktailHatZutat.cocktail_id
          AND CM_CocktailHatZutat.zutat_id=CM_Zutat.id
) group_attr
GROUP BY id;
```

because you use subquery